# Why am I getting an "Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById error" but my code still works sometimes

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an on edit code that works sometimes, but not others and I can't figure out why. I went to the executions tab and apparently my trigger runs but the simple trigger fails every single time (even the times when the code runs as I want it to). I've added my code as well as my trigger and the error.

**Created Trigger**
[image: Created Trigger]

**Executions Log**
[image: Executions Log]

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const cs = e.source;
  const cel = e.range;  
  const s1 = cs.getActiveSheet().getName();
  const trng = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1TaBpBZN1dg57vjPt1ldZ1Cqdt-3JeWtmP_A9p-mI4Mk');
  const s2 = trng.getSheetByName("TimeZones");
  const ZONES = s2.getDataRange().getValues();
  const col = cel.getColumn();
  const rw = cel.getRow();
  var dpd = cel.getValue();

  if(s1 == '3193:RENA' && col == 5 && rw < 15){
    var st = cel.getValue();
    for (var i=0;i<52;i++){
      if(ZONES[i][0] == st){
        tz = ZONES[i][2];
        cel.offset(0,1).setValue(tz);
        cel.setFontWeight(400)
      }
    }
  }

   if(s1 == '3193:RENA' && col == 7 && rw < 15){
    var dpd = cel.getValue();
    cel.setValue("-"+dpd)
    cel.setFontWeight(400)
    }
```

I deleted and re-added the trigger but apparently, it's the simple trigger that is giving me problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have one function with two triggers (one "simple", one "installable") - that's going to create problems: you only want ONE trigger. The "simple" trigger is created for any function named `onEdit`. Then, you created an installable `onEdit` trigger. Total triggers = two.

A simple trigger can modify the file they are bound to, but cannot access other files because that would require authorization. Since you have an instance of `openById()`, a simple trigger won't cut it.

Solution:

- rename the function from `onEdit(e)` to, say `setFont(e)`
- the "simple" trigger will be automatically deleted
- delete the installable trigger for `onEdit(e)`
- create a new installable trigger for `setFont(e)`

---

On a tangent, Google says "a macro is a series of recorded actions within Google Sheets. Once recorded, you can activate a macro to repeat those actions later with a menu item or shortcut key. You can both create and update your own macros in both Google Sheets and the Apps Script code editor." [ref](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1#1)

But your script is much more than a macro; you are evaluating the sheet name, column and row - this is something that is naturally seen in an app script.

Comment: I did what you suggested and now I don’t see the error for the simple trigger, but script just doesn’t work

Comment: Another question, I do have a different macro on the sheet should I be putting it on a new file?

Comment: @RenaMariee Two things: 1) "but script just doesn’t work"... that's not really very helpful; please describe in detail "how/when/where/why" it doesn't work, how do you know it doesn't work, what outcome did you expect and how is the actual outcome different to the expected outcome, etc... 2) "I do have a different macro on the sheet should I be putting it on a new file?" That's a little ambiguous - what do you mean "different macro" &/or "new file"?

Comment: It was mentioned that my script isn't a macro so I was wondering if I needed to move it from the default macro.gs file. As for the script, I have a list of accounts where the state and time zone, when I update the state it should automatically update the time zone however it doesn't. Nothing happens at all but it's showing the script completed in the executions log.

Comment: "It was mentioned that my script isn't a macro so I was wondering if I needed to move it from the default macro.gs file". Yes. If you have a/any script that isn't a macro (even though it is in macro.gs), then the script should be managed in the Project Editor (Main Menu > Extensions> Apps Script). I suggest that you copy the function from macro.gs, and paste into code.gs (or whatever script file you choose); then delete the script from macros.gs.

Comment: "As for the script,"... There's not enough information to resolve this script. You should post this as a new question; explain the scenario; provide some sample data (and layout) in a table, and give example(s) of the expected outcome based on the sample data.